# Finite Subset In Compact Metrizable Space

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness, solution-verification

I'm attempting to prove the following statement:

Let $X$ be a compact metrizable space. Let $F \subseteq X$ be a finite set in $X$. Then $X-F$ is compact iff every $x \in F$ is isolated.

Proof Attempt:

($\rightarrow)$ Suppose $X-F$ is compact. Assume by contradiction that there is some $z \in F$ that is not isolated. The given any open set $O$ with $z \in O$, we must have $O\cap F$ infinite as $X$ is T1 and $z$ is a limit point of $F$; a contradiction as $F$ is finite. (I'm worried about not using the hypothesis here)

($\leftarrow$) Suppose $F \subseteq X$ is finite and contains only isolated  points. I aim to show that $X-F$ is closed and therefore compact as closed subsets of compact spaces are compact... (I'm not sure how to proceed from here)

Comment: If $z\in F$ is not isolated, then the open sets $U_n=\{x\in X:\ d(x,z)>1/n\}$ cover all of $X\setminus F$, but since inside each $D_n=\{x\in X:\ d(x,z)<1/n\}$ there are points of $X$ other than $z$, then there are no finitely many $U_n$ that cover $X$.

Comment: If each $z\in F$ has an open $U_z$ such that $U_z\cap X=\{z\}$, then $X\setminus F=V^c$, for $V=(\bigcup_{z\in F}U_z)^c$ is closed. Assume that $V_i$, for $i\in I$ is an open cover of $X\setminus F$. Then $V,V_i$, for $i\in I$ is an open cover of $X$. Since $X$ is compact, then there are finitely many $V,V_1,v_2,...,v_n$ that cover $X$. Therefore, $V_1,V_2,...,V_n$ cover $X\setminus F$.

Comment: @MoonLightSyzygy Does the forward direction I attempted not work? Isn't true that if $z \in F$ is not isolated it must be a limit point of $F$ as given any open set $U$ with $z \in U$ we have $U \cap F \neq \theta$ and $U \cap F \neq \{ z \}$. And as X is T1 we must have $U \cap F$ infinite?

Comment: If $X=[0,1]$ and $F=\{0,1\}$. Then $[0,1/2)$, and any open set inside it, contains infnitely many points of $X$, but from $F$ is only contains $\{0\}$, not infinitely many elements of $F$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You assumed that, given $x\in F$, “$x$ is an isolated points” means “$x$ is an isolated point of $F$”, whereas it actually means that $x$ is an isolated point of $X$.

$\implies$ Suppose that $X\setminus F$ is compact. Then $X\setminus F$ is closed and therefore $F$ is an open subset of $X$. But, in a metric space, a set which is both finite and open must consist of isolated points only.

$\Longleftarrow$ Let $\mathcal U$ be an open cover of $X\setminus F$. If $F=\{p_1,\ldots,p_n\}$, then $\mathcal U\cup\{p_1\}\cup\{p_2\}\cup\cdots\cup\{p_n\}$ is an open cover of $X$. Therefore, it has a finite subcover $\{U_1,U_2,\ldots,U_N\}$. But then$$\{U_1,U_2,\ldots,U_N\}\setminus\bigl\{\{p_1\},\{p_2\},\ldots,\{p_n\}\bigr\}$$ is a finite subcover of $\mathcal U$.